# Телеграмм бот выдает '<function <lambda> at 0x000002746AD4A280>', заместо одной строки из списка (библиотека aiogram)

Tags: python, aiogram

```
ordinary_speech = ['Здесь какой-то строковый элемент', 'И здесь тоже']
random_message = lambda: random.choice(ordinary_speech)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['noun'])
async def noun(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, random_message)
```

Был бы очень рад вашей помощи...

Answer (score 2):

При вызове функции надо поставить `()`

```py
await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, random_message())
```